# Как вставить большое изображение в блок меньшего размера?

Tags: html, css

Есть блок `.column` который имеет определенный размер (220px в ширину).
В блок вставляется картинка большего размера(850px в ширину). И на данном этапе эта картинка заполняет это блок(т.е. становится 220px).

Как сделать, чтобы она вставлялась со своим размером (850px)?

```css
.content { display: inline-block; }
.column {float:right; width:225px;}

.single-slide {
  width: auto;
  max-width: inherit;
}

.single-slide img {
  width: auto;
  max-width: inherit !important;
  max-height: inherit !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">  
    <div class="column">
      <div class="slider">
        <div><img src='https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/2c/d0/19/2cd0197c5eb8c1f84e81734f97e80cd3.jpg' /></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Убрать у картинки `max-width: 100%`.

Comment: У нее нет этого значения

Comment: `img { width: auto; max-width: inherit; }`

Comment: Картинку не удержишь простой установкой ширины родителю: https://jsfiddle.net/answ4j4v/ Смотрите что там у родителя.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Возможно где-то еще заданы стили для responsive img, поэтому можно добавить `img { width: auto; }`:

```css
.column {
  width: 220px;
}

img {
  width: auto;
  max-width: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div class="column">
  <div class="slider">
    <div><img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/58/46/3a/58463a4dd0aa2cd68ba00a81868712eb.png"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

P.S: Возможно, что у `.column` задан `overflow: hidden;` и изображение просто обрезается из-за этого, но это как предположение.

---

**Update:**

Вообщем проблема в .column { width: 220px; } Для чего Вы задаете такие размеры, если хотите, чтобы внутри находился слайдер с картинками в 850px?! Не совсем понятно.

```js
$(".slider").slick({
  slidesToShow: 1,
  arrows: false
});
```

```css
.column {
  width: 220px;
}


.column img {
  width: auto;
  max-width: inherit;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.min.css" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.min.js"></script>
  
<div class="column">
    <div class="slider">
    <div>
      <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/58/46/3a/58463a4dd0aa2cd68ba00a81868712eb.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div>
       <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/58/46/3a/58463a4dd0aa2cd68ba00a81868712eb.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div>
       <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/58/46/3a/58463a4dd0aa2cd68ba00a81868712eb.png" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Если нужна фиксированная ширина картинок в слайдере и именно в 850px, то стоит задать такую ширину и самому слайдеру:

```js
$(".slider").slick({
  slidesToShow: 1,
  arrows: false
});
```

```css
.column {
  width: 220px;
}

.slider {
  width: 850px;
}

.column img {
  width: auto;
  max-width: inherit;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.min.css" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.min.js"></script>
  
<div class="column">
    <div class="slider">
    <div>
      <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/58/46/3a/58463a4dd0aa2cd68ba00a81868712eb.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div>
       <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/58/46/3a/58463a4dd0aa2cd68ba00a81868712eb.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div>
       <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/58/46/3a/58463a4dd0aa2cd68ba00a81868712eb.png" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

А вот если хотите, что бы ширина все-таки была 220px и слайдер вмещался в эту ширину, то все-таки лучше адаптировать и картинки под эту ширину:

```js
$(".slider").slick({
  slidesToShow: 1,
  arrows: false
});
```

```css
.column {
  width: 220px;
}

.column img {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.min.css" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.min.js"></script>
  
<div class="column">
    <div class="slider">
    <div>
      <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/58/46/3a/58463a4dd0aa2cd68ba00a81868712eb.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div>
       <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/58/46/3a/58463a4dd0aa2cd68ba00a81868712eb.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div>
       <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/58/46/3a/58463a4dd0aa2cd68ba00a81868712eb.png" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

P.S: есть еще вариант - убрать ширину `.column {width: 220px; }` и отображать слайдер с изображениями тех размеров какие есть (`variableWidth: true`):

```js
$(".slider").slick({
  slidesToShow: 1,
  arrows: false,
  variableWidth: true
});
```

```css
.column img {
  width: auto;
  max-width: inherit;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.min.css" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.min.js"></script>
  
<div class="column">
    <div class="slider">
    <div>
      <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/58/46/3a/58463a4dd0aa2cd68ba00a81868712eb.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div>
       <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/58/46/3a/58463a4dd0aa2cd68ba00a81868712eb.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div>
       <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/58/46/3a/58463a4dd0aa2cd68ba00a81868712eb.png" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо, но если раньше она уменьшалась, то теперь она обрезается

Comment: @dmitriy, ну вот значит задан `overflow: hidden;` стоит попробовать его убрать

Comment: а можно еще как-то переопределить картинку? overflow: hidden нет, смотрю и в коде и в верстке

Comment: @dmitriy, приведите тогда весь код html\css

Comment: обновил код в вопросе, но это, наверное, не поможет)

Comment: К слову такое поведение появилось после добавления slick slider, до этого картинка вставлялась как надо. но и в слике я все уже перелопатил

Comment: @dmitriy стили в слике содержат свойства для картинки `max-width: 100%; display: block;`

Comment: @dmitriy и у всего слик-контейнера есть `overflow: hidden`.

Comment: чуточку обновила ответ, может быть что-то найдете для себя подходящее.

Answer (score 1):

По умолчанию изображения ведут себя именно так, как вы описали. Вам надо убрать стили, которые ограничивают / изменяют размеры картинки.

```css
.block {
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 220px;
  padding: 5px;
}

img {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class=block>
  <img src="http://placeimg.com/800/600/any" />
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо, но я не хочу убирать стили родителя, я хочу переопределить изображение

Comment: я и не убирал стили родителя, а просто показал, что картинка вылазит за пределы блока - это ее стандартное поведение.